# InvalidCastException deserializing a SqlException with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: .net-core, json.net, sqlexception

I have an error deserializing a JSON string containing a SqlException instance.

Environment information:
 - .NET Core: version 2.2
 - Newtonsoft.Json: version 11.0.1

Result Error:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'System.Guid'.'

Stack:

```
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException..ctor(SerializationInfo si, StreamingContext sc)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateISerializable(JsonReader reader, JsonISerializableContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
```

Here a test that reproduce my issue:

```
[Fact(DisplayName = nameof(TestShitSingleSqlEx2))]
public async Task TestErrorSingleSqlEx2()
{
    string json = @"{
    ""$type"": ""System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, System.Data.SqlClient"",
    ""ClassName"": ""System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"",
    ""Message"": ""A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"",
    ""Data"": {
                ""$type"": ""System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal, System.Private.CoreLib"",
    ""HelpLink.ProdName"": ""Microsoft SQL Server"",
    ""HelpLink.EvtSrc"": ""MSSQLServer"",
    ""HelpLink.EvtID"": ""0"",
    ""HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl"": ""http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink"",
    ""HelpLink.LinkId"": ""20476"",
    ""SqlError 1"": ""System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)""
    },
    ""InnerException"": null,
    ""HelpURL"": null,
    ""StackTraceString"": ""   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)\\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\\n   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\\\\a\\\\1\\\\s\\\\Ix.NET\\\\Source\\\\System.Interactive.Async\\\\Select.cs:line 106\\n   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\\\\a\\\\1\\\\s\\\\Ix.NET\\\\Source\\\\System.Interactive.Async\\\\AsyncIterator.cs:line 98\\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\\n   at System.Collections.Generic.AsyncEnumerableHelpers.ToArrayWithLength[T](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\\\\a\\\\1\\\\s\\\\Ix.NET\\\\Source\\\\System.Interactive.Async\\\\AsyncEnumerableHelpers.cs:line 48\\n   at System.Collections.Generic.AsyncEnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\\\\a\\\\1\\\\s\\\\Ix.NET\\\\Source\\\\System.Interactive.Async\\\\AsyncEnumerableHelpers.cs:line 16\\n   at XXXXXX.Manufacturing.Sublot.EntityFramework.Repositories.SublotRepository.LoadDataModelAsync(IEnumerable`1 ids) in /src/Sublot/Sublot.EntityFramework/Repositories/SublotRepository.cs:line 28\\n   at XXXXXX.Manufacturing.EntityFramework.Repository.DbMultiMapRepository`3.OnGetAsync(IEnumerable`1 ids)\\n   at XXXXXX.Manufacturing.Repository.MultiRepository`1.GetAsync(String id)\\n   at XXXXXX.Manufacturing.Sublot.Cqrs.Handlers.SublotHandler.Handle(MoveSublotCommand command) in /src/Sublot/Sublot.Cqrs.Handlers/SublotHandler.cs:line 193\\n   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.HandlerInvoker`1.Invoke()\\n   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.DispatchIncomingMessageStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)\\n   at Rebus.Sagas.LoadSagaDataStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)\\n   at Rebus.Sagas.Exclusive.NewEnforceExclusiveSagaAccessIncomingStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)\\n   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.ActivateHandlersStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)\\n   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.HandleRoutingSlipsStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)\\n   at Rebus.Retry.Simple.FailedMessageWrapperStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)\\n   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.DeserializeIncomingMessageStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)\\n   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.HandleDeferredMessagesStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)\\n   at Rebus.Retry.FailFast.FailFastStep.Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func`1 next)\\n   at Rebus.Retry.Simple.SimpleRetryStrategyStep.DispatchWithTrackerIdentifier(Func`1 next, String identifierToTrackMessageBy, ITransactionContext transactionContext, String messageId, String secondLevelMessageId)"",
    ""RemoteStackTraceString"": null,
    ""RemoteStackIndex"": 0,
    ""ExceptionMethod"": null,
    ""HResult"": -2146232060,
    ""Source"": ""Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider"",
    ""WatsonBuckets"": null,
    ""Errors"": null,
    ""ClientConnectionId"": ""00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000""
    }";

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    }; ;

    var cmd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException>(json, settings);
}
```

I already tested that with TypeNameHandling.None (default value) it works. But i had this error in a production environment (using rebus v5.4.0) and i'm not confidet to modify TypeNameHandling for all messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be in the cast of the property ""ClientConnectionId"": ""00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000""

In fact if you remove it from the json string it works.

The problem is that the code that converts the type is inside the class
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Here is the source code that performs class deserialization:

```
private SqlException(SerializationInfo si, StreamingContext sc) : base(si, sc)
        {
            HResult = SqlExceptionHResult;
            foreach (SerializationEntry siEntry in si)
            {
                if ("ClientConnectionId" == siEntry.Name)
                {
                    _clientConnectionId = (Guid)siEntry.Value;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

source: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlException.cs

the problem lies in that cast:
(Guid)siEntry.Value;

Answer (score 0):

I've posted [the issue](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/524) on GitHub SqlClient. The fix implemented by the project team is on the way of being merged so it should be available in versions newer than Microsoft.Data.SqlClient v1.1.2.
DummyRick, consider that (by looking at the stacktrace of the SqlException) it looks like you are using the *legacy* System.Data.SqlClient package instead of the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.